# Doctrine schema.yml generator

Tags: schema, doctrine, generator

I am pretty new to doctrine. I made two small projects with doctrine for my own but now I am about to create big project for my client. The project will have more than 50 tables. Is there any way of generating schema.yml? I tried DB Designer and converted it to schema.yml, but I still had to check and rewrite the definitions by hand. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

you should try ORM Designer (http://www.orm-designer.com/), which covers most of your needs. You can design database just the same way you are used to design in DB Designer and than export to Doctrine (or Propel) schema.yml or schema.xml files (import from existing definitions is also possible). It was developed for our web developers, so it supports symfony plugins, Subversion etc. You can find screencasts and how-tos describing ORM Designer + Symfony + Doctrine/Propel on www.orm-designer.com. If you have any questions, please feel free to ask on our forum or just email us.

Frantisek Troster
ORM Designer
www.orm-designer.com

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with doctrine cli.

Create a cli script by following [these detailed steps](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/cookbook/1_1/en/code-igniter-and-doctrine:setup-command-line-interface).

Then run: `./doctrine generate-yaml-db` from the script directory.

Hope this helps.